# Installation Failed, app already exsist. Но приложения нет на устройстве

Tags: android

Написал свое приложение на для android. Установил. Все норм. 
Нужно было удалить приложение. Удалил.

При попытке установить это приложение ещё раз, возникает ошибка: Installation Failed, app already exsist.

Перезагрузка смартфона не помогла.
Что я упускаю?

Answer (score 0):

Есть оболочки на некоторых телефонах, которые хранят приложение даже после "удаления". Для этого нужно использовать их системный агент в настройках и удалить по правде. На моей памяти было парочку таких например LG V20. Проверьте мб в этом дело.

Comment: Пробовал удалять и просто "с рабочего стола", и через настройки, и очищать весь мусор с телефона после удаления приложения. Результат один и тот же. meizu m3s flyme 6.2.0.0g

Comment: проверьте в настройках разработчика, если оптимизация вашей ОС, если что уберите флаг. 

Также попробуйте почистить проект. Clean Project -> Build APK -> Build Project